# ext4_mb_generate_buddy Filesystem Error

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm facing the below filesystem error in SSD type disk with software raid configured machine. Is there any possible cause for this issue? Thank you for your help in advance.

Kernel Version: 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 OS Version: CentOS 7.6.1810

```
EXT4-fs error (device md0): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:757: group 82800, block bitmap and bg descriptor inconsistent: 32768 vs 28640 free clusters 
EXT4-fs error (device md0): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:757: group 82816, block bitmap and bg descriptor inconsistent: 32768 vs 28640 free clusters 
EXT4-fs (md0): error count since last fsck: 70 
EXT4-fs (md0): initial error at time 1617606033: ext4_mb_generate_buddy:757 
EXT4-fs (md0): last error at time 1617606034: ext4_mb_generate_buddy:757
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no disk I/O errors accompanying these error messages, it looks like filesystem corruption.

The `...error at time...` values seem to be Unix timestamps: you could convert them to human-readable time values like this:

```
$ TZ=UTC date -d @1617606033
Mon  5 Apr 07:00:33 UTC 2021

$ TZ=UTC date -d @1617606034
Mon  5 Apr 07:00:34 UTC 2021
```

The filesystem seems to have accumulated 70 errors within a single second of time. Find out what happened in your system at about that time. Were there any disk I/O errors logged?

You might want to use `smartctl` or similar tool to check the health status of the individual disks configured into the software RAID set.

Also use `cat /proc/mdstat` to check the state of your software RAID set: if you don't actively monitor your RAID set, or the monitoring has failed, you might see the first indications of trouble only when one disk in the RAID set has *already failed* and *another* one is starting to fail... and if you even suspect that you might be in such a situation, take an extra backup ASAP, while the RAID set still works. Then start working to replace the failing disks.

If the underlying disks seem to be in good health, you should unmount `/dev/md0` and run a filesystem check on it at your earliest convenience. But take a backup first, just in case.